# Why git clone works only in Powershell running as administrator?

Tags: git, powershell, ssh

I configure `ssh key` for my `Gitlab` account and want to `git clone` my repo, but cloning works only in `Powershell` running as administrator.

The command below works the same in both cases (with admin rights and without):

```
ssh -T git@my.gitlab.host.com
```

The output is: `Welcome to GitLab, @username!`

How I can make to work `git clone` without running `Powershell` as administrator?

---

*Update 1*: 
`whoami` output also the same for both cases (with admin rights and without)

*Update 2*: 
`git clone` command error:

> git@my.gitlab.host.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal:
> Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

*Update 3*: 
`git push` command fails with the same error. Problem with access to private `ssh key` located in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` ?

*Update 4*: 
I set the default `ssh` command for `git` (`ssh -Tv`) as *VonC* suggested, but with this command: 
`git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -Tv"` (setting the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` was not worked for me) 
First 19 lines output for `git pull` command (no admin):

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to my.gitlab.host.com [my.gitlab.host.ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /t/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
```

First 9 lines output for `git pull` command (admin):

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/my_user/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/my_user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for my.gitlab.host.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to my.gitlab.host.com [my.gitlab.host.ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
```

So it looks like in no-admin mode it even do not try to find keys/configs in right location. Any ideas of this behavior?

Comment: Can you create files in the clone directory without admin rights? What is the error message for `git clone`?

Comment: updated the question with error; yes I can create files/directories there without admins rights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both instances (admin or no admin), set first:

```
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tv"
```

That way, you will see which key is accessed (from which folder), and you can compare both session.

---

> It looks like in no-admin mode it even do not try to find keys/configs in right location.

What it does look like is, in no-admin mode, there is an environment variable `HOME` set to `T:\` or `/t`.
Type `set HOME` in a CMD to confirm.

Setting that variable to `%USERPROFILE%` would mean using the right path.

Comment: I checked the `HOME` variable on both modes with command: `echo "HOME : $HOME"`  ; The output is the same: `C:\Users\my_user`

Comment: Ok, I do not know why, but when I have set additionally `HOME` variable with value `C:\Users\my_user`  in environment variables - it have started to work.

Comment: @Egor `$HOME` only works in `git bash`. What about `set HOME` in CMD? Anyway, setting it explicitly is preferable indeed.